# SELECT DISTINCT values and INSERT INTO table

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, distinct, sql-insert

I want to take a column with values that repeat multiple times and get that value only once and store it for later use, but at the same time I would like to get another value in the same row as that distinct column.

```
A      B       C
32263  123456  44
32263  123456  45
32263  123456  46
32264  246802  44
32263  246802  45
32264  246802  46
32265  369258  44
32265  369258  45
32265  369258  46
```

A, B, C represent three columns. Ignore C for now.

My question is: How can I get this information in this table and store it for I can use it later in the script?

Here is what I tried:

```
use databaseName

select distinct A from tableName
order by A
```

The result is:

```
A
32263
32264
32265
```

I'm trying to get it to also give me B's value. (Note it does not matter at all which row I get since no matter what A I choose the value of B will be the same for given A.) We are ignoring C for now.

The result should be:

```
A      B
32263  123456
32264  246802
32265  369258
```

Now, once I get it like that I want to insert a row using the values I got from the query. This is where C comes in. I want to do something like this:

```
use databaseName

insert into tableName (A, B, C)
values (32263, 123456, 47)
```

Of course I don't want to put the values directly inside of there, instead have some type of loop that will cycle through each of the 3 distinct A values I found.

In short, my table should go from:

```
A      B       C
32263  123456  44
32263  123456  45
32263  123456  46
32264  246802  44
32263  246802  45
32264  246802  46
32265  369258  44
32265  369258  45
32265  369258  46
```

To:

```
A      B       C
32263  123456  44
32263  123456  45
32263  123456  46
32263  123456  47 -
32264  246802  44
32263  246802  45
32264  246802  46
32264  246802  47 -
32265  369258  44
32265  369258  45
32265  369258  46
32265  369258  47 -
```

I placed dashes next to the newly added rows to help you see the changes.

I figure I should perhaps do some type of loop that will cycle through all three distinct A values, but my problem is how to do that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's an errant `32263` in the middle of the `32264` section.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO... SELECT` statement on this,

```
INSERT INTO tableName (A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, MAX(C) + 1
FROM tableName
GROUP BY A, B
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2051/2)

Comment: Cool. Opened my eyes to import from a populated table over to a codes table:
`INSERT INTO code_mst (code_value,code_field)
SELECT DISTINCT app_brand,'app_brand'
FROM app_mst`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name) x
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish correctly, you should be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table
SELECT A, B, MAX(C) + 1
FROM Table
GROUP A, B
```

This should insert a row for every distinct combination of `A` and `B` as well as increment `C`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using windowing functions.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, C + 1
FROM(
select A, B, C, MAX(C) OVER(PARTITION BY A, B) AS MAXC
FROM TABLENAME 
) AS NEW_ROWS
WHERE C = MAXC
```

Comment: This would add many duplicates, OP just wants 1 row per grouping.

Comment: @GoatCO Updated my query to filter.  A group by will work most of the time until you just want to group by A.  Just wanted to introduce windowing function since they are very useful.