# Insert into the same table using distinct column

Tags: sql, distinct, sql-insert

Using this table as an example:

```
TBL_TEST

FIELD_A    |    FIELD_B    |    FIELD_C   |
AAA        |     124       |      12      |
BBB        |     457       |      12      |
CCC        |     347       |      12      |
AAA        |     990       |      13      |
BBB        |     387       |      13      |
CCC        |     213       |      13      |
```

I need to insert a `14` on `FIELD_C` for each distinct existing `FIELD_A`. `FIELD_B` is a static value for example `888`.

I needed this final result:

```
TBL_TEST

FIELD_A    |    FIELD_B    |    FIELD_C   |
AAA        |     124       |      12      |
BBB        |     457       |      12      |
CCC        |     347       |      12      |
AAA        |     990       |      13      |
BBB        |     387       |      13      |
CCC        |     213       |      13      |
AAA        |     888       |      14      |
BBB        |     888       |      14      |
CCC        |     888       |      14      |
```

I have tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TEST(FIELD_A,FIELD_B,FIELD_C)
SELECT DISTINCT(FIELD_A),888,14) FROM TBL_TEST
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `dstinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always operates on *all* columns of the select list.

Comment: Please also tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Check this post, it will be helpful for you as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014183/select-distinct-values-and-insert-into-table?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TEST(FIELD_A,FIELD_B,FIELD_C)
SELECT DISTINCT FIELD_A ,888,14 FROM TBL_TEST
```

Please also make sure there's no duplicated keys.